# django oauth2 rest authentication flow for mobile apps

Tags: django, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to figure out which is the best flow to interact from my mobile app to my api.

I'm using those packages:

https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit
 http://www.django-rest-framework.org

I would like to have this flow:

1. The user compile the registration view on my mobile app with user & password
2. The user submit the registration
3. My app make a request to my backend to obtain a token **for the app**
4. App with the token make a call to the user registration api
5. My backend register the user, login it and return a **user token** for future calls.

Is my flow correct?
If I use Resource owner password-based and I make request like this:

```
 curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=username&password=password" -u "client_id:client_secret" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/oauth/token/
```

I get:

```
 {"access_token": "09Vf0HD5nCPSEvLAnjxrghZPHfvE4c", "token_type": "Bearer", "expires_in": 36000, "refresh_token":"yDmovryDlGhkLVV6T2rTgFQxnNtguq", "scope": "read write groups"}
```

But If I'm tring to get an access token for my app with this:

```
 curl -X POST -d "grant_type=client_credentials" -u "client_id:client_secret" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/oauth/token/
```

I get:

```
 {"error": "unauthorized_client"}
```

So my doubt is:
How should I setup my application?
**Which Authorization grant type my oAuth2 application should have?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resource owner password credential` authenticates your application on behalf of a user (the resource owner) thus grants access to data related  to that user.

`client_credential` grant type is needed when you want to authenticate your application and not the user. The issued access token won't be bound to an user but to an application and this tokens usually only allow access to application related data.

If you want to enable this grant in DOT you should choose "Client Credential" in the application creation form.

The flow you described looks ok, but keep in mind that you need two applications: one for the client credentials grant and one for the password grant.

On the server side, the registration endpoints should have a permission check that allow requests only from client_credential access_tokens. 
When the registration succeed (say 201) you can obtain a "user token" using username and password before deleting them.

Just one question, I don't get why you need python social auth. There is no mention about it in the flow you described.

Comment: Ok, so now everything is clear. I was already thinking about creating two applications: one for the app (actually only to make registration api call) and the second one for the users. Recap: http://dpaste.com/1TASM5X.txt   So, should I store in my mobile application a pair of client_id, client_secret? one for app and one for app that acts on behalf of my users? Never seen this, so I'm asking if is it common to use two applications. 

When you say "before deleting them" you mean delete the user/pass in the app and use the token obtained instead for future calls, right? THANKS!

Comment: Or maybe the 4 step could be done server side with django code?

Comment: You should never store client_secret in your application because it is not a Confidential client, so just set the application to public.
On the other hand, a client_credential MUST only be used by confidential clients, as per the RFC6749. So you have a problem.

Usually we register users through a standard webview, and we keep a Public application that uses password grant_type, so we don't have to store client_secret.

Finally, yes you must discard username and password after you obtained the token.

Comment: Maybe am I missing something: http://dpaste.com/1WWF262.txt ?
My app is now public with client credentials, I don't get how should authenticate my app to make the register user call.

Comment: Authorization: Token header is invalid. You must use Authorization: Bearer

Comment: I would like to build the experience inside the app without opening a new web view for the login. Any hints on the flow without storing the secret inside my app? Also what involves setting the app as public?
Register flow: https://www.evernote.com/l/AOaoXbimiy9GCLe0KE-D6-iA8QUBlD7vXJI

Other api calls flow:
https://www.evernote.com/l/AOZtVeMsc_JPfLnHvwAGk9RxVcFS7DBNEqc

I Still have doubts If I should create two apps or not.

Thanks again.